# Numpy float128 is not giving a correct answer

Tags: numpy, floating-point, precision, ode, solver

I created a differential equation solver (Runge-Kutta 4th order method) in Python. Than I decided to check its results by setting the parameter mu to 0 and looking at the numeric solution that was returned by it.

The problem is, I know that this solution should give an stable oscillation as a result, but instead I get a diverging solution.

The code is presented below. I tried solving this problem (rounding errors from floating point precision) by using numpy float128 data type. But the solver keeps giving me the wrong answer.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def f(t,x,v):
  f = -k/m*x-mu/m*v
  return(f)

def g(t,x,v):
  g = v
  return(g)

def srunge4(t,x,v,dt):
  k1 = f(t,x,v)
  l1 = g(t,x,v)

  k2 = f(t+dt/2, x+k1*dt/2, v+l1*dt/2)
  l2 = g(t+dt/2, x+k1*dt/2, v+l1*dt/2)

  k3 = f(t+dt/2, x+k2*dt/2, v+l2*dt/2)
  l3 = g(t+dt/2, x+k2*dt/2, v+l2*dt/2)  

  k4 = f(t+dt/2, x+k3*dt, v+l3*dt)
  l4 = g(t+dt/2, x+k3*dt, v+l3*dt)

  v = v + dt/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
  x = x + dt/6*(l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)
  t = t + dt
  return([t,x,v])

mu = np.float128(0.00); k = np.float128(0.1); m = np.float128(6)

x0 = np.float128(5); v0 = np.float128(-10)

t0 = np.float128(0); tf = np.float128(1000); dt = np.float128(0.05)

def sedol(t, x, v, tf, dt):
  sol = np.array([[t,x,v]], dtype='float128')
  while sol[-1][0]<=tf:
    t,x,v = srunge4(t,x,v,dt)
    sol=np.append(sol,np.float128([[t,x,v]]),axis=0)
  sol = pd.DataFrame(data=sol, columns=['t','x','v'])
  return(sol)

ft_runge = sedol(t0, x0, v0, tf, dt=0.1)

plt.close("all")
graf1 = plt.plot(ft_runge.iloc[:,0],ft_runge.iloc[:,1],'b')
plt.show()
```

Am I using numpy float128 in a wrong way?

Comment: Why do you think that float128 is the issue here? For that matter, what have you done to diagnose the problem so far?

Comment: Did you try making `dt` smaller?

Comment: For Mad Physicist: I solve an exact copy of this problem using an spreadsheet add-in called Xnumbers (which provides extended floating point precision) and it gives me the correct answer for mu=0, which is an stable (non-diverging) oscilation.

Comment: For Paul Panzer: I will try it, although I think this will only exarcerbate the problem. I will keep you posted on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing in `srunge4` the association of `k` and `l` to `x` and `v`. Per the function association and the final summation, the association should be `(v,f,k)` and `(x,g,l)`. This has to be obeyed in the updates of the stages of the method.

---

In stage 4, it should be `t+dt` in the first argument. However, as `t` is not used in the derivative computation, this error has no consequence here.

---

Also, you are destroying the float128 computation if you set one parameter to a float in the default float64 type in `dt=0.1`.

---

The code with these corrections and some further simplifications is

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mu = np.float128(0.00); k = np.float128(0.1); m = np.float128(6)
x0 = np.float128(5); v0 = np.float128(-10)
t0 = np.float128(0); tf = np.float128(1000); dt = np.float128(0.05)

def f(t,x,v): return -(k*x+mu*v)/m
def g(t,x,v): return v

def srunge4(t,x,v,dt): # should be skutta4, Wilhelm Kutta gave this method in 1901
  k1, l1 = (fg(t,x,v) for fg in (f,g)) 
  # here is the essential corrections, x->l, v->k
  k2, l2 = (fg(t+dt/2, x+l1*dt/2, v+k1*dt/2) for fg in (f,g)) 
  k3, l3 = (fg(t+dt/2, x+l2*dt/2, v+k2*dt/2) for fg in (f,g))
  k4, l4 = (fg(t+dt  , x+l3*dt  , v+k3*dt  ) for fg in (f,g))

  v = v + dt/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)
  x = x + dt/6*(l1+2*l2+2*l3+l4)
  t = t + dt
  return([t,x,v])

def sedol(t, x, v, tf, dt):
  sol = [[t,x,v]]
  while t<=tf:
    t,x,v = srunge4(t,x,v,dt)
    sol.append([t,x,v])
  sol = pd.DataFrame(data=np.asarray(sol) , columns=['t','x','v'])
  return(sol)

ft_runge = sedol(t0, x0, v0, tf, dt=2*dt)

plt.close("all")
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
ft_runge.plot(x='t', y='x', ax=ax[0])
ft_runge.plot(x='t', y='v', ax=ax[1])
ft_runge.plot.scatter(x='x', y='v', s=1, ax=ax[2])
plt.show()
```

It produces the expected ellipse without visually recognizable changes in the amplitudes.

Comment: For LutzL: the problem you mention would make a completely diferent graph (not an slowly increasing oscillation. About the switch betweeb dv/dt and dx/dt, I don't think this is the case because the new Vs and Xs are being calculated from Ks and Ls respectively and the Ks are calculated from F and the Ls from G. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Nearly fully replaced answer with new error analysis with tested corrections.

Comment: For LutzL: Thanks!. I will carefully check each change you made in the original function and try finding the error source in my code. Regarding the name, yes, it was Kutta who originally presented this method and Runge was a co-discoverer. The problem here is my mother tongue which is Brazilian Portuguese. To understand what I'm saying change the "K" in Martin Wilhelm's last name with a "p" and delete one of the "t"s. Take this "word", go to Google Translate and ask it to translate from Brazilian Portuguese to English and you will get the idea, kkkkk. I will keep you posted on my findings. Tks

Comment: For LutzL: Just to close this question, yes you were right since the beginning. I was mixing (x') equation with (v')'s. I have accepted your answer as the correct one.

Comment: For LutzL: And by the way, the numbers not even need to be of type float128. Good old floats suffice to produce the correct results.

Comment: Yes. You only exceed the precision of float64 if dt is substantially lower than 1e-2. float128 should be good for step sizes dt down to 1e-5.

Comment: Just to clarify, part of the reason why using `float128` does not make a difference compared to using `float64` for you might be because the former doesn't give any extra precision. It seems like whether `float128` is actually available other than as a "padded alias" to `float64` might depend on your system. See [NumPy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#extended-precision).